# Question about prepositions and word-order

Tags: prepositions, word-order

What is more natural for you to say this:

> Yesterday, [via / through / on] website I talked to my friend named Johnny.
>
> Yesterday, I talked to my friend named Johnny [via / through / on] website.

Comment: you might specify what the website is. you could say 'yesterday, .... [via / on / through] Skype'. I think all are fine.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context and the situation. Most of the time, I would find this one more natural:

> Yesterday, I talked to my friend Johnny using Skype.

However, it depends on what I'm trying to emphasize. If I had never used Skype before yesterday, and I'm excited about this new tool I can use to talk with my friends, I might say:

> Yesterday, I used Skype to talk with my friend Johnny.

because the main thing I'm trying to stress is the **tool I used**, not the person I spoke with. (In the first sentence, I'm putting more emphasis on who I conversed with, not the tool I used to communicate.)

Funny, though: when I'm talking about a letter I receive in the mail, I almost always put the person it was from at the end:

> Yesterday, I got a letter from my friend Johnny.

and not:

> Yesterday, my friend Johnny sent me a letter.

That's because, if I got the letter yesterday, chances are Johnny sent it a few days ago, not yesterday. However:

> Yesterday, my friend Johnny handed me a note.

is perfectly fine, because the transaction is instantaneous. I would not say:

> Yesterday, I was handed a note by my friend Johnny.

because that is in the passive voice.

---

Notice also that I have removed the word *named*. When talking about *my friend Johnny*, the word *named* is usually omitted.